# Using Linq.js to compare every member of an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, typescript

I'm building a filtering function for an internal grid tool, and I'm a bit stuck on how to use linq.js with Typescript

Our grid is comprised of a data object. This data object has a member called "rows" that is an array of objects.

The array is technically classed as "any", but in general they have a fixed property set (that has to match the grid).

I need to query every field in this array and if any of the fields match the filter, they should be added to a list.

The structure is something like this

```
grid
----data
--------rows
------------Row
---------------cell
------------------prop1
------------------prop2
---------------cell
------------------prop1
------------------prop2
---------------cell
------------------prop1
------------------prop2
------------Row
---------------cell
------------------prop1
------------------prop2
---------------cell
------------------prop1
------------------prop2
---------------cell
------------------prop1
------------------prop2
```

An example of the object may be similar to:

```
{  
   "grid":{  
      "rows":[  
         {  
            "row":[  
               {  
                  "cells":[  
                     {  
                        "fieldName":"test",
                        "value":"testing1",
                        "displayText":"testing 1"
                     },
                     {  
                        "fieldName":"test 2",
                        "value":"testing2",
                        "displayText":"testing 2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "row":[  
               {  
                  "cells":[  
                     {  
                        "fieldName":"test",
                        "value":"testing1",
                        "displayText":"testing 1"
                     },
                     {  
                        "fieldName":"test 2",
                        "value":"testing2",
                        "displayText":"testing 2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In pseudo code, using foreach loops, it might look something similar to the following:

```
List items = new List();
string comparator = "testing";

foreach(row item in grid.rows) {
    foreach(cell c in item.cells) {
        foreach(var field in c.fields) {
            if(field.value.contains(comparator)
                items.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's a working snippet. The issue is that I will never know what the property names are for the rows inside of the Grid class itself. It's all handled by a polymer template.

```
private _filterData(filter: string): any {
    var filteredRows: Array<any> = new Array();
    var rel = this.el;
    if (filter != null) {
        Enumerable.from(rel.data.rows).forEach(n => {
            Enumerable.from(n.cells).forEach(c => {
                Object.keys(c).forEach(p => {
                    if (c[p].indexOf(filter)>=0) {
                        filteredRows.push(n); 
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
    return filteredRows;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy... you don't give any details but the "outline" depends on what you want to do.  You can get a **list of rows** that have fields of interest like this:

```
 var result = rows.Where(row => row.Fields.Any(<<function to filter>>));
```

If you want just the **list of the fields** of interest use SelectMany, like this:

```
 var result = rows.SelectMany(row => row.Fields).Where(<<function to filter>>);
```

---

Based on comment below and question edits:

```
 var inessence = rows.SelectMany(row => row.cells)
                     .SelectMany(cell => cell.fields) 
                     .Where(field => field.value.constains(comparator));
```

Comment: In essence I want to be able to loop through every member inside of every cell inside of every row, and if their value contains the value of my filter string, add them to the list.

Comment: @Jdsfighter - In essence this is what the 2nd line above does.  I'll make you another example

Comment: @Jdsfighter - saw your edit -- there is your answer.  If you have your heart set on a list add `ToList()` after the `Where`

Comment: The big issue is that the grid component doesn't really know what the cell fields are going to be called. They're defined by a template file, but even in the template file I cannot find where they map directly to the source code. The closest I've found is the sort function, and it's not making a lot of sense.

Comment: well you sure aren't making sense.  I've answered your question.

Comment: I've made one final edit to my post with a working snippet. It should give you an idea of why my methodology was so backwards.

Comment: The unlinq aspect of your solution is that it is not lazy.  This is because you are returning a list instead of an enumeration, if you filtered instead of pushing you would have a lazy result which should perform better.

Comment: For whatever reason, I was not able to iterate over the fields (properties), using any other method except for the one I posted. I'm not entirely sure what the cause it, but in every browser tested, it simply skipped over it.

Comment: Well you are not using C# linq (since C# has no forEach function) so I'm not quite clear exactly what library you are using -- a little hard to go deeper.

Comment: I'm actually using Linq.JS, a javascript equivalent of linq, which I stated above.